# How to remove unique rows in two data frame in R?

Tags: r

Here are data frames that I have:

```
Symbols    Val
  AA        5
  AA        6
  BB        7
  BB        9 
  CC        8
  CC        7

Symbols    Val
  AA        2
  AA        34
  CC        41
  CC        1
```

I'm going to combine two data frames, but first one has some more data in Symbols column. As you see "BB"s are unique compared to second data frame. So, I need to remove two rows (BB) in the first one.
I know how to remove in one data frame, not in two different one. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting, a combined data frame with the unique values removed from `df1`?  How do you want to combine the two data frame, by binding rows or columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `intersect` ing 'Symbols' from both the dataset and use `subset` to return those in the first dataset

```
v1 <- intersect(df1$Symbols, df2$Symbols)
df1new <- subset(df1, Symbols %in% v1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the two datasets by stacking their rows, you can use `bind_rows()` and [`filter(across())`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) to leave out the unique `Symbol` values in each data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  filter(across(Symbols, ~. %in% intersect(df1$Symbols, df2$Symbols)))

  Symbols val
1      AA   5
2      AA   6
3      CC   8
4      CC   7
5      AA   2
6      AA  34
7      CC  41
8      CC   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep unique `Symbols` in `df2` and join the two dataframes.

This can be done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% inner_join(df2 %>% distinct(Symbols), by  ='Symbols')

#. Symbols Val
#1      AA   5
#2      AA   6
#3      CC   8
#4      CC   7
```

Base R :

```
merge(df1, data.frame(Symbols = unique(df2$Symbols)), by = 'Symbols')
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[unique(df2, by= 'Symbols')[, 1], on = 'Symbols']
```